# Не получается подключиться к БД в Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Пытаюсь подключиться к БД на удалённом сервере, WorkBench выдаёт ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Более старые версии паролей устарели в последних версиях MySQL. начиная с 5.7.5, вам нужен хешированный пароль, см. также [password-hashing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-hashing.html)

Аналогичный комментарий есть в англоязычной версии SO

Comment: Я устанавливал всё по умолчанию, все самые последние версии компонентов mysql. Не ясно как решить проблему, видимо нужно что-то прописывать в my.ini. К localhost mysql подключается, а к удалённому нет.